# Error getting location on Activity in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have to put the actual value of my location in a variable but I have this error:

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
> ```

My code is:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mCurrentLocation = location;
    Latit = mCurrentLocation.getLatitude();

    Location objLoc = new Location("");
    objLoc.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
    objLoc.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    startLocationUpdates();
}

public void locInicio(View v) {
    TextView inicioLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.eInicioLat);
    Latit = mCurrentLocation.getLatitude();
    inicioLat.setText((int) Latit);

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.adicionar);
    buildGoogleApiClient();
}
```

In other activity I can get the value with `onLocationChanged` but it always returns an error.

> 04-16 23:01:43.447  12954-12954/greetrack.estg.ipvc.greentrack
>   E/Zygote﹕ MountEmulatedStorage() 04-16 23:01:43.447 
>   12954-12954/greetrack.estg.ipvc.greentrack E/Zygote﹕ v2 04-16
>   23:01:43.467  12954-12954/greetrack.estg.ipvc.greentrack E/SELinux﹕
>   [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL,
>   cateogry: NULL 04-16 23:01:55.647 
>   12954-12954/greetrack.estg.ipvc.greentrack E/ViewRootImpl﹕
>   sendUserActionEvent() mView == null 04-16 23:01:56.447 
>   12954-12954/greetrack.estg.ipvc.greentrack E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: greetrack.estg.ipvc.greentrack, PID: 12954
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
>               at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4221)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5155)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20747)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
>        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4216)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5155)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20747)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a
>   null object reference
>               at greetrack.estg.ipvc.greentrack.Adicionar.locInicio(Adicionar.java:53)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4216)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5155)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20747)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)

Comment: Post the full stack trace.

Comment: ok, i look in my question

Comment: You simply need to take care of cases where location is null in `onLocationChanged`. e.g. `if (location == null) return;` as the fist line in the method.

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference at greetrack.estg.ipvc.greentrack.Adicionar.locInicio(Adicionar.java:53)

You simply need to take care of cases where location is null in `onLocationChanged`. e.g. `if (location == null) return;` as the fist line in the method.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location == null) return;

    mCurrentLocation = location;
    Latit = mCurrentLocation.getLatitude();

    // by the way - why do you do this??
    Location objLoc = new Location("");
    objLoc.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
    objLoc.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());
}

public void locInicio(View v) {
    TextView inicioLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.eInicioLat);

    // here is your problem
    if (mCurrentLocation == null) return; 

    Latit = mCurrentLocation.getLatitude();
    inicioLat.setText((int) Latit);

}
```

Comment: But this is my problem, the location its always null